# Using hashtag in my nav menu messes up my site (sticky nav not showing - jquery error)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, navigation

I am having trouble understanding this issue.

My site uses a 2nd (sticky) navigation when you scroll down on the page.

When I add custom links to the menu containing a hashtag (e.g. /subpage#heading5), so that you can visit an anchor directly via menu button, the sticky menu is not showing up any more.

When working properly, the sticky menu is shown when you scroll to a certain point using jquery.

I get an error only when I start to scroll on the page and the same error accumulates as I scroll more. Error:

> "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   /about-us#who-we-are"

For debugging reasons I am only using one hashtag in my navigation (nav button"About us -> Who we are"), using this custom link:

> /about-us#who-we-are

Site: [CLICK](http://abieslabs.spletnoprogramiranje.com/)

Best regards!

EDIT: Omidam81 helped me to partialy resolve the problem.. The error is still present in console, so if anybody has an idea, im still on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I checked your code on your website, if you change the href of your menu from '/about-us#whoweare' to 'about-u#whoweare' it work.

**if you ask why?** i don't know :).

Comment: I tried your your suggestion, but it did not work for me. Than i tried with full url (http://abieslabs.spletnoprogramiranje.com/about-us/#who-we-are) instead of end only (/about-us/#who-we-are) and it works :) Will have to manualy change the urls when migrating the site, but better this than nothing. Thanks for nudging me in the right direction!

Comment: your welcome, i checked it on google chrome console.